# Faster alternative to the (V A V^T).diagonal in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am looking for a faster alternative for the following code.

```py
rows = 30
cols = 10**3
v_mat = np.random.rand(rows,cols)
a_mat = np.random.rand(cols,cols)

b_vec = (v_mat @ a_mat @ v_mat.T).diagonal()
```

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @Lagerbaer Yes, it works. The reference solution is 4 times faster in my case. Thank you.

Comment: `@` can be used without the diagional: `(v_mat[:,None,:]@a_mat@v_mat[:,:,None])[:,0,0]`.   But `einsum` with `optimize=True` is better, as is the linked `(A.dot(B) * A).sum(-1)`

Comment: @hpaulj, Thanks. I will try the `einsum` code.